# Using GAE Datastore Multitenancy for Java Results A Blank Page

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have been trying to use Datastore Multitenancy for weeks now. And I can't seem to make it work. Every time I try to run it on my own (computer) server, it does not seem to display anything at all. I have also tried to publish it on the GAE server, but it still does not seem to display.

What I am trying to acheive is to work on a Company Entity with another sub-entity of Users and Data which is not connected to any emails, Oauth, or third party applications. The Company Entity, being the namespace, will separate all the data and users of each company. This way, it will contain users and all its other data without leaks.

I tried to make sure that the application has its own NamespaceFilter Class for the Company Entity. What causes the blank page? (Or maybe the right question is, what am I doing wrong?)

**Update:**

There are no errors on the code and there are no exceptions whatsoever. However, the JSP pages that I am trying to display is just gone without any information how it does not display.

Comment: Have you checked the console/logs for any exceptions?

Comment: Honestly, I have not checked the exceptions. Thanks for remininding me. Will update the Question soon.

Comment: No probs. Just curious, it has been more than a week, any updates? People with similar issues might be grateful for any solutions that you found.

Comment: Thanks for being persistent. I created another program for it. I currently don't see any Exceptions on it when I tried to run it. The code does not show any errors at all. I don't think I am displaying anything, because my code does not create methods for display. But, I thought, the JSP is still going to show up. Currently, I am on revision 37. I created a repository for it. Here it is:  http://code.google.com/p/pawnsoftware/.

Answer (score 0):

Multitenancy can only be used with Google Apps. Here is what is stated by Google App Engine on Implementing Multitenancy.

```
Most App Engine developers will use their Google Apps domain as the current 
namespace. Google Apps lets you deploy your app to any domain that you own, 
so you can easily use this mechanism to configure different namespaces for 
different domains. Then, you can use those separate namespaces to segregate 
data across the domains.
```

**Clarification:** It is `Google Apps` that lets you deploy to any domain and use Multitenancy. You need to use `Google App Engine` API that can make you use Multitenancy. `Google Apps` and `Google App Engine` should be connected. By registering Domains to Google Apps, you can use Multitenancy. Therefore, if you use Users, it needs to be registerd with Google Apps.

Comment: It says on the first line "`Most App Engine Developers will use their Google Apps Domain` as the current namespace". So I still have some questions: Can an external domain hosted in external servers serve Multitenancy?